# In python control the string format when writing to file in an iterator

Tags: python-3.x, io, iterator, string-formatting

I have some data that comes in regularly multi-line format, e.g. 3 lines per record, as `r_in` :

```
name1
34
981
name2
12
321
name3
331
1299
...
```

I would like to use python to mingle around with data, and write to a new output file `r_out` with TAB separated values, here just two columns (name and a ratio between two variables).

I made a primitive framework parser to handle input files and give me the output using str.format(). But I might not fully understand this function since the output is somewhat staggered. Or is it something with the way I use the iterator's `next()`

```
def parser(r_in, r_out):
   with open(r_in, "r") as r_in, open(r_out, "w") as r_out:    
     try:     
       while True:      
         #Grab the three lines with next()
         name, dat1, dat2 = next(r_in), next(r_in), next(r_in)

         #Mingle around with data, say the ratio between dat1 and dat2         
         res = round(int(dat1)/int(dat2), 2)

         #Write to r_out
         r_out.write("{}\t{}".format(name, res))

     except:
       pass
```

The out put looks like:

```
name1
  0.03name2
  0.04name3
  0.25me@chrx:~/projects/test$
```

(Yes, Im rather new to  Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `next` on a file iterator, you get the line with the termination char.

Whereas `int` strips it off, it's (fortunately) not the case for strings.

So you can fix it by doing:

```
name, dat1, dat2 = next(r_in).rstrip(), next(r_in), next(r_in)
```

also you're forgetting the termination at the end of the line. So all-in-one fix:

```
r_out.write("{}\t{}\n".format(name.rstrip(), res))
```

(no need to `rstrip` again if already done when reading `name`, which is more logical if `name` is used elsewhere, noone needs a linefeed in the `name` at first)